# Are C compilers like gcc smart enough to bit shifts in place?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

Unlike assembly code, in C there is no way to bit shift a value in place. To shift the bits in variable an assignment must always be performed:

```
x = x << 3;
```

Are compilers like gcc smart enough to realize that this is an in-place bit shift and compile it like this:

```
shl x, 3
```

or will the compiler put the result first in a register, then move it back into x (which would require two extra unnecessary instructions).

Comment: why dont you write the code, turn up the optimizer and look at the generated assembly

Comment: You haven't even mentioned the architecture where such an instruction exist. Shift a memory location in place? I doubt there are many archs that even support it. But GCC is smart enough to do much more complex optimizations.

Comment: Even if the instruction exists, the microcode has to do the moves.

Comment: BTW no assignment is needed in C, you can write `x <<= 3;`. What the compiler makes out of this is another story.

Comment: You'd need to go shopping for another compiler when it generates *that* code.  Much smarter ways to do this, have a look-see at what your compiler generates.

Comment: @HansPassant What's wrong with that code *assuming* such an instruction exist? (which is highly unlikely as I have never seen a hardware capable of performing in-place arithmetics on memory locations..)

Comment: LEA is in general the smarter way to multiply a number by 8.  Depends on what happens with the variable next.

Comment: Michael, How is >>= not an assignment? Sure it's a compound assignment but it's still an assignment.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/

Comment: This might have been a meaningful question in 1985. Compilers have gotten a lot better since then. Yes, GCC uses LEA to load-and-shift all at once.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir Only in the same sense that `++` is an assignment.

Comment: @IanAbbott: [assignment operators](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16) according to the C standard.

Answer (score 2):

Any good compiler with optimization turned on will handle bit shifts efficiently.

Compilers will keep small objects in registers when feasible and efficient and will not store them to memory even if you write assignment statements, until they are forced to by circumstances.

Additionally, it is not desirable on typical modern processors to try to shift the bits of a value in memory. Generally, memory hardware does not have any capability to manipulate stored values. To change the value of something in memory, it must be moved to the processor (loaded), changed, and moved back (stored). Whether this is done in one instruction or several is not generally an indication of how fast or efficient it is, because the processor still has to do the individual load, shift, store operations, and the performance of those is highly dependent on the processor model.

Except in exceptional programming situations, you should not be worrying about performance at this level.

Answer (score 0):

what did you see when you tried it? why not just try it?

unsigned int fun ( unsigned int x )
    {
        return (x<<3);
    }
    Disassembly of section .text:

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e1a00180    lsl r0, r0, #3
   4:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <_fun>:
   0:   1166            mov r5, -(sp)
   2:   1185            mov sp, r5
   4:   1d40 0004       mov 4(r5), r0
   8:   0cc0            asl r0
   a:   0cc0            asl r0
   c:   0cc0            asl r0
   e:   1585            mov (sp)+, r5
  10:   0087            rts pc

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <fun>:
   0:   531d7000    lsl w0, w0, #3
   4:   d65f03c0    ret

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <fun>:
   0:   8d 04 fd 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(,%rdi,8),%eax
   7:   c3                      retq   

00000000 <fun>:
   0:   42 18 0c 5c     rpt #3 { rlax.w r12     ;
   4:   30 41           ret         

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <fun>:
   0:   050e                    slli    x10,x10,0x3
   2:   8082                    ret

unsigned int x;

void fun ( void )
{
    x=x<<3;
}
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e59f200c    ldr r2, [pc, #12]   ; 14 <fun+0x14>
   4:   e5923000    ldr r3, [r2]
   8:   e1a03183    lsl r3, r3, #3
   c:   e5823000    str r3, [r2]
  10:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  14:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
```

and so on

Comment: I don't understand that disassembly.

Comment: then why ask a question if you dont understand assembly language to understand the answer?

Comment: I understand enough to know that using 3 operations including a mov is slower than a single shift. I am not expert enough to understand the disassembly above. Are you just trying to make this as hard as possible? I asked a pretty simple question.

Comment: so when you tried it what did you find?  show your code and tell us what you think it is doing. simply asking us to teach a class is not what so is for, it is about I have some code I think it should do A but it does B.  Change your question to that format.

Comment: You have been asked enough questions to now know how to ask the question and what information to provide.

Comment: Actually I have made it easier, providing several examples using different instruction sets.